# Repeat data until next MAX date is found and continue - SQL SparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a calendar table

| c_date |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-01-02 |
| 2020-01-03 |
| 2020-01-04 |
| ..... |
| 2020-12-31 |

I have the main table

| Value | col_A | col_B | col_C | col_Date (yyyy-mm-dd) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | 2020-12-01 |
| 2 | X | Y | Z | 2020-04-02 |
| 3 | X | Y | Z | 2020-04-03 |

I want the output as date to get repeat for Calendar days starting from col_Date in second table and repeat until next MAX date

Output should be:

| col_A | col_B | col_C | c_Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | 2020-12-01 | 1 |
| A | B | C | 2020-12-02 | 1 |
| .. | .. | .. | 2020-04-02 | 1 |
| X | Y | Z | 2020-04-03 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | 3 |
| X | Y | Z | 2020-12-31 | 3 |

Explanation :  First record should get repeated upto 2020-04-02.( Because 1 data is there ). But next record should continue repeat upto the year end and it should take the value from the MAX Date of that Month.

What I tried: Correlated query, which works in SQL Server but not in SparkSQL (Databricks)

```
select A, B, C, c_date FROM calendar_table x
inner join main_table m on x.col_date = (select max(c_date) from main_table h
  where h.A = m.A and h.B = m.b and h.C = m.C and h.c_date <= x.col_date )
where 1=1
```

NOT Working in SparkSQL . Need to do without using Co-relation
NOTE :  It should start only from the MAX of that Month. Please help rewrite the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead()` to get the next date and then `join`:

```
select m.col_A, m.col_B, m.col_C, c.c_Date, m.value
from (select m.*,
             lead(c_date) over (order by c_date) as next_date
      from maintable m
     ) m join
     calendar c
     on c.c_date >= m.c_date and
        (c.date < m.next_date or m.next_date is null)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. ! This lead() is the lead, I was missing. Thank you very much